# Is there any integration of Socket.IO for Quart?

Tags: python, socket.io, quart

I'm using Quart and I'd really like to use Socket.IO with it, but I couldn't find Socket.IO integration for Quart, only for Flask. Should I try the flask version or there's no way?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way at the moment, as this [issue](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/209) shows it isn't supported. The hard way would be to alter python-socketio to add support.

Comment: @pgjones Hey, I followed your link and found it's available now. [The latest reply](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/209#issuecomment-804809987) is in March 2021.